# How to pass and return Intent (Camera)

Tags: android, android-intent

I need something little different than usual.

I have like 20 buttons that can take image. I use same handler. Depending on what button clicked - I just pass "ButtonIndex" inside intent to camera. I would like to get that value back in OnActivityResult so I know what to process.

Is that possible? I tried to read from returned intent but value get's lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. You can use `startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`
 The requestcode will be returned when the activity exits.

Comment: I was going to use requestCode but now I have to reserver RANGE of them because I have other activities that I start for result and have to handle all of those together